# find a and b such that the limit will exist and find the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I am given this question $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-a-bx^2}{x^4}$$

And asked to find the $a$ and $b$ such that the limit exists and also to compute the limit

---

My solution:

Let $t$=$\sqrt{1+x}$.
Then the Maclaurin polynomial is : $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$$ 
Now plugging in $x^2$ for x we get $$\sqrt{1+x^2}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)$$

and from the common Maclaurin polynomial we have that $e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+ \mathcal{O}(t^3)$. Plugging in $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ for $t$ we get:

$$e^{1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6) 
}$$
which in turn is: 
$$e^{1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6) 
}=1+\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^6)$$ 
hence we have: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1+\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right)+\mathcal{}O(x^6)-a-bx^2}{x^4}$$
And i argue that $a=2, b=1/2$ and the $\lim=-1/8 $

However the book disagrees with me and argues that the they should be $a=e, b=e/2$ and limit $=0$

i mean i can see how theyd done it, by not expanding $e^t$ but by only expanding $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ however what i dont understand how come we didnt get the same values or at least the same value for the limit?

Comment: If there are any typos its because i copied and pasted the formulas, i do apologize for that and do appreciate it if you pointed them out.

Comment: Those power series are only useful near zero.  Close to infinity, the error terms dominate.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. "I am given..." is all you say. You mean, "I am give that (limit) exists, and to find $a,b$."

Comment: There must be something wrong here. Is the limit maybe taken for x to zero and no to infinity? Because if $x \to \infty$ in your above term, the exponential always goes to infinity much faster than all the other terms and no matter what $a$ and $b$ are, you get $\infty$ as a result.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are right, i double checked my book and the $x\rightarrow 0$ not infinity, sorry.

Comment: What is the value of $e^{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ at $x=0$? Your power series gives it a value $1$, but it should be $e$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=e^{1+x}$. By your reasoning, since $1+x=1+x+O(x^2)$, you get that:

$$f(x)=1+(1+x)+O(x^2)$$

But that isn't correct. If it was correct, then $f(0)=2$, but we know $f(0)=e$.

Now, if you did the full substitution you'd get:

$$f(x)=1+(1+x)+\frac{(1+x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(1+x)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

The problem is that the terms $\frac{(1+x)^k}{k!}$ keep adding to the constant and linear terms.

What you really should get is $$e^{1+x+O(x^2)}=e^{1}\left(1+\left(x+O(x^2)\right)+\frac{\left(x+O(x^2)\right)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)$$

Now, $\left(x+O(x^2)\right)^2=O(x^2)$. So you get:

$$e^{1+x}=e+ex+O(x^2)$$

In your case, you get:

$$\begin{align}e^{1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6) 
}&=e\left(1+\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}\right)^2}{2!}+O(x^6)\right)\\
&=e\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\frac{x^4}{8}+O(x^6)\right)\\
&=e+\frac{e}{2}x^2+O(x^6)
\end{align}$$

And you get $a=e,b=\frac{e}{2},$ and $\lim = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. When you write
$$
e^{1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6) 
}=1+\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^6)
$$ it is **wrong**, since it is **not** right that, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right)^m=\mathcal{O}(x^6),\qquad m=2,3,\cdots.
$$
Please look at
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right)^m.
$$
You can't neglect the previous quantities.

Do you see the issue?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews and Oliver i do really apologize for the confusion, the x goes to $0$ on and *NOT* infinity.

Comment: @Reddevil OK, did you get the point?

Comment: No not really no

Comment: Please, what is the value of the limit in my answer above?

Comment: @Oliver if i didnt misinterpret anything here i get $(-1/8) ^m$ im sure i messed up somewhere along the way

Comment: by divding everything by $x^4$ i get $(\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{8}+ \mathcal{O}(x^2)$

Comment: each of which goes to zero except $-\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: @DanielWagner you are correct, i thought that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}$

Comment: @Reddevil I've you been able to understand your mistake?

Answer (score 5):

**Simplified computation:**

Let $\sqrt{1+x^2}=t+1$, so that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-a-bx^2}{x^4}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e\cdot e^t-a-bt(2+t)}{t^2(2+t)^2}\\
=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e+et+\dfrac{et^2}2+\dfrac{et^3}{3!}+\cdots-a-2bt-bt^2}{4t^2}.$$

Then it is obvious that we need

$$a=e,b=\frac e2$$ and the third coefficient is

$$\frac e2-\frac e2=0.$$

Comment: The trick is to avoid computing the composition of two functions.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the squares, we have

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sqrt{1+x}}-a-bx}{x^2}.$$

By adjusting $a$ and $b$, we can certainly get rid of the linear terms and the limit will exist.

So let's compute the Taylor development of $f(x):=e^{\sqrt{1+x}}$.

$$f(0)=e=a,$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{1+x}}}{2\sqrt{1+x}},f'(0)=\frac e2=b,$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{1+x}}}{4(1+x)}-\frac{e^{\sqrt{1+x}}}{4(1+x)^{3/2}},f''(0)=0.$$

Hence the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

First rewrite the equation replacing $x$ by $X$: Thus we require $L=\lim_{X\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^{\sqrt{1+X^2}}-a-bX^2}{X^4}$

Now let $x:=\sqrt{1+X^2}$, then $X^2=x^2-1$ with $X^4=(x^2-1)^2$ and $x\rightarrow 1$ as $X\rightarrow 0$.

Now, we have $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{e^x-a-b(x^2-1)}{(x^2-1)^2}=\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}e^x-a-b(x^2-1)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}(x^2-1)^2}=\dfrac{e-a}{0}$

Thus $L$ is not defined (finite) unless $e-a=0$. Now if $a=e$ we have $L=\frac{0}{0}$, so we may use L'Hopital.

Consider then $L=\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}e^x-2bx}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}4(x^2-1)x}=\dfrac{e-2b}{0}$
which is not defined unless $e-2b=0$.

Thus for a finite limit it is necessary that $b=\frac{e}{2}$ and $a=e$.

Again use L'Hopital:
$L=\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}e^x-e}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}12x^2-4}=\dfrac{e-e}{8}=0$ as required.